# Issues with Java substring method

Tags: java, string, substring

I wrote a program that prompts a user to input his/her full name First , middle , last. I'm attempting to break that name down into three separate pieces using the substring method by locating each white space in the string. Once each white space is found the following portion of the name is stored in a new string variable.

The issue I'm having is that the middle name is storing both middle and last because the counter isn't stopping correctly as you will see in my below code so my question is how can I fix this.

Please note, I do not want to split the string, I do not want to use a StringTokenizer, I do not want to use Arrays, I already know how to do it that way. All I need to know is how to fix my counter, what I am trying to do will work this way I'm not looking for a new way to do this; I'm only working with substring and charAt.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String name = "", 
           firstName = "",
           middleName = "",
           lastName = ""; 

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);       

           System.out.print("Please enter your name 'First Middle Last': "); 
           name = in.nextLine();



           int i = 0; 

  while(i < name.length())
  {   
      if(name.charAt(i) == ' ')
      {
           firstName = name.substring(0, i); // Starts at 0 ends at first occurence of ' '

         /* middleName = name.substring(i + 1, i); Should start at i + 1, 
            or one postion after the previously located white space and 
            then end at the next occurence of ' '

           ^ The above does not work, and this is where the issue is      
             happening, how ever if I do the following */

             middleName = name.substring(i + 1, name.length()); 

           /* This does work but because the endIndex is name.length() it  
               runs the length of name and grabs both the middle and last name.*/   
                     i = name.length();


             }
                ++i;
           } 



    System.out.print("\nDisplayed with last name first: " + "\nLast Name: " + lastName + "\nFisrt Name: " + firstName + "\nMiddle Name: " + middleName);

  }

}
```

The output this produces looks like this

```
Please enter your name 'First Middle Last': First Middle Last

Displayed with last name first:
Last Name:
First Name: First
Middle Name: Middle Last
```

As you can see first Name is displayed correctly. 
Middle name is not because it included "Last" and not just "middle"

Comment: Please consider the value in [answers that use a different technology other than what is asked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268190/answers-that-use-a-different-technology-than-what-is-asked/268228#268228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `indexOf(' ')` and `lastIndexOf(' ')` to find first space and last space

- everything before 1st space is `firstname`
- everything after last space is `lastname`
- the rest in the middle is `middlename`

Pseudocode:

```
firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' '));
middleName = name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1, name.lastIndexOf(' '));
lastName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: thank you for the response, when you initially made your comment I went right to the java docs and came to the conclusion you're correct! Thank you for your response, and more over thank you for being the only person here who actually decided to give me the information I needed and not what I specifically said I didn't need!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `substring` you can use `split` function:

```
String string = "Peter Ralph Joseph"; //Here the string
String[] parts = string.split(" "); //Here the string it is divide taking as reference the space
System.out.println(parts[0]); //Peter
System.out.println(parts[1]); //Ralph
System.out.println(parts[2]); //Joseph
```

In my opinion, it is easier and faster to do it with `split` function.

Comment: You're missing the point, It has nothing to do with efficiency or what is easier. I'm using substring I am not as I stated using split, nor stringTokenizer etc.. I asked a simple question. How can I fix the counter lol

Comment: @Afflicted Oh, sorry. Then you can use `indexOf(' ');` to take the reference to the first space and `lastIndexOf(' ');` to find the last space as @radoh said in his answer. Anyway, I think you should use other functions to get this behaviour instead of `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running through a loop with `charAt`, if you really want to use `substring` you could just do:

```
int firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(' ');
String firstName = fullName.substring(0, firstSpace);

int secondSpace = fullName.indexOf(' ', firstSpace+1);
String middleName = fullName.substring(firstSpace+1, secondSpace);

String lastName = fullName.substring(secondSpace+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mode = 0;
var last = 0;
for(i=0;i<name.length();i++)
{   
    if(name.charAt(i)==' '||i==(name.length()-1))
    {
       mode++;
       var text = name.substring(last, i-last);
       last = i+1;
       if(mode==1) { firstName = text; }
       else if(mode==2) { middleName = text; }
       else if(mode==3) { lastName = text; break; }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it in the following way:
   no need to run the while loop.

```
firstName=name.substring(0,name.indexOf(' '));
 middleName=name.substring(name.indexOf(' ')+1,name.lastIndexOf(' '));
 lastName=name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(' ')+1,name.length());
```